# best way to structure class for binding to datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class shown below.

```
class RegionSale
{
    DateTime DateSale;
    string Region;
    double DollarAmount; 
}
```

At run time the code wouldn't know how many RegionSale objects would be required, this is fine as I can just create List of RegionSale objects.

The problem I have is I'm now be asking to display the data via a wpf datagrid but in the format shown below,

```
 DateS      UK      US      EUxUK   JAP     Brazil
 2015-12-03 23634   22187   NULL    NULL    NULL
 2015-12-04 56000   22187   NULL    NULL    NULL
 2015-12-14 56000   10025   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

So I could create a new class like below (however feel this is a bad idea)

```
class RegionSaleNew
{
    DateTime DateSale;
    double UK;
    double US;
    double EUxUK;
    double JAP;
    double Brazil;
}
```

As I mentioned earlier I won't know at runtime the number of regions so the class above seems like a bad idea, however its obviously easy to bind to the datagrid.

The question is how best to structure my class bearing in mind the format of the datagrid & without knowing the number of regions until runtime? Is reflection a good idea?

Comment: You should crate a class for this. You can youse `ObservableCollection(yourClass)` then and just bind the colums to the class properties. if you want nulls, you could use `double? UK; double?...`

Comment: Yes I need to create a class to bind to the datagrid. I'm just wondering what is the best way to design my class

Comment: Is this for viewing only or also needs to be editable?

Comment: the datagrid would just be for viewing

Answer (score 0):

I would write a class that derives the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and create a property for every region like in your example.

Then I would use a `ObservableCollection<myClass>` and bind to the properties.

```
class RegionSaleNew : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime DateSale;
    double _uk;
    .....
    public double UK
    {
        get { return _monitor; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _uk) return;
            _uk = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    // Add all properties here

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

In XAML you could then bind like this

```
...
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="UK" Binding="{Binding UK, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
...
```

All you have to do then is to set the `DataGrid.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection` or in XAML `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding myObservableCollection} ... </DataGrid>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was interested in the same subject, so it was the target of the my first SO question [Cross tabular data binding in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169375/cross-tabular-data-binding-in-wpf). The provided answer there covered it in general, but not for the `DataGrid` specific binding. So my conclusion was that the solution should be based on some `System.ComponentModel` concepts:

(1) Custom [PropertyDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation for providing "virtual" properties.
(2) The item class implementing [ICustomTypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) to expose the "virtual" properties per item
(3) The collection class implementing [ITypedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow automatic data grid column creation from the "virtual" properties.

Having your model

```
class RegionSale
{
    public DateTime DateSale;
    public string Region;
    public double DollarAmount;
}
```

and data

```
IEnumerable<RegionSale> data = ...;
```

the "virtual" properties can be determined at runtime by simply getting a distinct list of the `Region` field:

```
var regions = data.Select(sale => sale.Region).Distinct().ToList();
```

For each region we'll create a property descriptor with region as `Name`, which later will be used as key into item internal dictionary to retrieve the value.

The items will be built by grouping the data by `DateSale`.

Here is the whole implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

class RegionSalePivotViewItem : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private RegionSalePivotView container;
    private Dictionary<string, double> amountByRegion;
    internal RegionSalePivotViewItem(RegionSalePivotView container, DateTime date, IEnumerable<RegionSale> sales)
    {
        this.container = container;
        DateSale = date;
        amountByRegion = sales.ToDictionary(sale => sale.Region, sale => sale.DollarAmount);
    }
    public DateTime DateSale { get; private set; }
    public double? GetAmount(string region)
    {
        double value;
        return amountByRegion.TryGetValue(region, out value) ? value : (double?)null;
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return container.GetItemProperties(null);
    }
}

class RegionSalePivotView : ReadOnlyCollection<RegionSalePivotViewItem>, ITypedList
{
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;
    public RegionSalePivotView(IEnumerable<RegionSale> source) : base(new List<RegionSalePivotViewItem>())
    {
        // Properties
        var propertyList = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
        propertyList.Add(new Property<DateTime>("DateSale", (item, p) => item.DateSale));
        foreach (var region in source.Select(sale => sale.Region).Distinct().OrderBy(region => region))
            propertyList.Add(new Property<double?>(region, (item, p) => item.GetAmount(p.Name)));
        properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyList.ToArray());
        // Items
        ((List<RegionSalePivotViewItem>)Items).AddRange(
            source.GroupBy(sale => sale.DateSale,
                (date, sales) => new RegionSalePivotViewItem(this, date, sales))
                .OrderBy(item => item.DateSale)
        );
    }
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return properties; }
    public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return null; }
    class Property<T> : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        Func<RegionSalePivotViewItem, Property<T>, T> getValue;
        public Property(string name, Func<RegionSalePivotViewItem, Property<T>, T> getValue) : base(name, null) { this.getValue = getValue; }
        public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(RegionSalePivotViewItem); } }
        public override Type PropertyType { get { return typeof(T); } }
        public override object GetValue(object component) { return getValue((RegionSalePivotViewItem)component, this); }
        public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }
        public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
        public override void ResetValue(object component) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return false; }
    }
}
```

**Sample test:**

*ViewModel*:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public RegionSalePivotView PivotView { get; set; }
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="263" Width="463" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotView}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Code behind*:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var data = new[]
        {
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 03), Region = "UK", DollarAmount = 23634 },
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 03), Region = "US", DollarAmount = 22187 },
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 04), Region = "UK", DollarAmount = 56000 },
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 04), Region = "US", DollarAmount = 22187 },
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 14), Region = "UK", DollarAmount = 56000 },
            new RegionSale { DateSale = new DateTime(2015, 12, 14), Region = "US", DollarAmount = 10025 },
        };
        DataContext = new ViewModel { PivotView = new RegionSalePivotView(data) };
    }
}
```

*Result*:

[image]